# PyCharm not finding Anaconda Python, giving "can't open file 'python': [Errno 2] No such file or directory?"

Tags: python, installation, pycharm, anaconda

I am new to Python. Installed Anaconda on my system.
I installed PyCharm too.
When I try to run a file from PyCharm I get this error message:

> C:\Python\Test\venv\Scripts\python.exe python 3.6
>   C:/Python/Test/while.py C:\Python\Test\venv\Scripts\python.exe: can't
>   open file 'python': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Set the path in windows for python

Comment: Your command line is very odd with the `python 3.6` in the middle and mixed slashes and backslashes.

Comment: bibounty> i did it still getting error. installed Python with Anaconda.

Comment: Could you please accept an answer if your question has been resolved, or else edit it to include more detail if not resolved?

Comment: Similar problem here. Conda C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe create -p C:\Users\me\.conda\envs\untitled -y python=3.7. Error: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe: can't open file 'create': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @Pedro77 I have a same problem. Did you find solution for this error?

Comment: @user2114537 No, I gave it up for now

Answer (score 13):

You have mentioned that you have already installed the Anaconda in your system. You can try the following,

1. Go to Project Interpreter in Pycharm
2. Under Conda Environment, choose the Existing Environment and select the python.exe from the Anaconda Installation folder in the Interpreter field.
3. Enable the option, Make available to all projects and click ok.

You should now be able to see the libraries in the Project Interpreter.

Comment: I was missing the "Make available to all projects" checkbox. After checking it, it stopped showing the said error. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Under Conda Environment, you can try to choose X:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have virtual environment installed without python version.
If you are new to Python, it may be better if you follow the easiest path:
download python 2.7 or 3.6 from [Python website](https://www.python.it/download/).

If you run the installer, you should find the python folder in C:\Python27 or C:\Python36.

Then you should assert that this folder is in windows paths, set them in Enviromental variables in System property.

For the last step you need to set Python interpreter in PyCharm:

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> Python Console -> Python interpreter

and set as interpreter the python.exe file in your X:/PythonNN folder

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and then solved it by running PyCharm as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are using is wrong, try:

```
C:\Python\Test\venv\Scripts\python3.exe  C:/Python/Test/while.py
```

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem with the Pycharm Community Edition (CE). Solved it by switching to Pycharm Professional.